# how to copy an array into somewhere else in the memory by using the pointer

Tags: c++

I am completely new in c++ programming. I want to copy the array called distances into where pointer is pointing to and then I want to print out the resul to see if it is worked or not.

this is what I have done:

```
int distances[4][6]={{1,0,0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,1,0,1,0,0}};

int *ptr;
ptr  = new int[sizeof(distances[0])];
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(distances[0]); i++){
   ptr=distances[i];
   ptr++;
}
```

I do not know how to print out the contents of the pointer to see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the size calculation of your `ptr` array is wrong. It only seems to work because the size of an `int` on your platform is `4`, which is also one of the dimensions in your array. One way to get the right size is

```
 size_t len = sizeof(distances)/sizeof(int);
```

Then you can instantiate your array and use `std::copy` to copy the elements:

```
int* ptr  = new int[len];
int* start = &dist[0][0];
std::copy(start, start + len, ptr);
```

Finally, print them out:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  std::cout << ptr[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

....
delete [] ptr; // don't forget to delete what you new
```

Note that for a real application you should favour using `std::vector<int>` over a manually managed dynamically allocated array:

```
// instantiates vector with copy of data
std::vector<int> data(start, start + len);

// print 
for (i : data)
  std::cout << i << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: I agree with u @juanchopanza

Comment: @juanchopanza: thanks for your excellent explanation. I came up with a new question..what do you recommend for copying the data from a source into where the pointer is pointing to in the real time.
for example: I am getting some data from a device. as long as I am running the application the data is producing.How can I copy these data into somewhere in the memory?

Answer (score 0):

use `cout` to print values like  `cout << *ptr;`

```
int distances[4][6]={{1,0,0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,1,0,1,0,0}};
int *ptr;
ptr  = new int[sizeof(distances[0])]; 

// sizeof(distances[0]) => 6 elements * Size of int = 6 * 4 = 24 ;
// sizeof(distances) => 24 elements * Size of int =  24 * 4 = 96 ;   
// cout << sizeof(distances) << endl << sizeof(distances[0]);

for(int i=0; i<sizeof(distances[0]); i++){
     ptr = &distances[0][i];
     cout << *ptr <<  " ";
     ptr++; 
}
```

**Explaination of your code**

```
ptr = distances[i] => ptr = & distances[i][0];
// To put it simple, your assigning address of 1st column of each row
 // i = 0 , assigns ptr = distances[0][0] address so o/p 1
 // i = 1, assigns ptr = distances[1][0] address so o/p 1
 // but when i > 3, i.e i = 4 , your pointing to some memory address because
// your array has only 4 rows and you have exceeded it so resulting in garbage values
```

I agree with  @juanchopanza solution, calculation of your pointer size is wrong

```
 int distances[3][6]={{1,0,0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0}};
 // for this case it fails because 
 // 6 elements * 4 = 24 but total elements are just 18
```

Use `sizeof(distances)/sizeof(int);`

Comment: Add `<< "\n"` or `<< endl` to the end for clarity.

Comment: no, it does not work. i want to have "1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0" in the output.

Comment: it just gives me 0 in the output.

Comment: @user2758510 before worrying about the output, you should concentrate on actually copying the data correctly. The size of your `ptr` array is only right by pure chance.

Comment: thanks a lot. regarding your comment added to the code, if the array was float then what would be the size of array?

Comment: if it was a float it would equal 24 , because size of float is also 4 bytes and elements are 6 so 6 * 4 = 24

Comment: @user2758510 again, that would be chance. There is nothing that guarantees that the size of a `float` or an `int` is 4. This way of doing things is just plain wrong.